# Expand UILabel Text

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make my app so that long text posts you don't have to scroll through but have an option to show all and show less (show less is default). I've been trying to do it but I'm not able to do it without changing all of the cells to "Show more" or "Show less". Here is how I make it initially show less by how many characters it has in it (Message = the post text, postCellObj = the object I use to call the cell class) this code is done in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
if messages.isEmpty == false {

        var messageString = messages[indexPath.row] as String
        var messageFinal = ""

        if count(messageString) >= 200 {
            var messageNs = messageString as NSString
            var messageFinal = messageNs.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 200))
            postCellObj.message.text = messageFinal as String + "..."

        } else {
            postCellObj.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]

        }

    }
```

If anyone knows how to do it, it would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Use `label.sizeToFit()` to adjust the text in UILabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use two labels for this design. The first label is for your original text, and the other one will show "Show All" or "Show Less".

The only one thing you have to do is to set the frame of the first label (original text).

The frame height for "Show All" could be calculated by line height (firstLabel.font.lineHeight)* number_of_lines_you_want. Remember to set the label property "numberOfLines" and "lineBreakMode" to "ByTruncatingTail".

The frame height for "Show Less" could be calculated by "sizeThatFits", which is supported by UILabel. The parameter "size" could be set to (frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

I don't familiar with swift, so I just describe what I will do with this design. Hope this helps!

Comment: I already have it adjust to the amount of text, that is in the cell. I just don't really know how to make it so if I click a button it will only change the text for that one cell.

Comment: You may need to change the height of cell and reload it (tableView.reloadData, tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, or tableView.reloadSections).